# Google Big Query - How to operate a shared Google Cloud Storage Bucket?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm sorry if the question is too stupid.

I want to share a Google Cloud Storage Bucket with my organization. Based on my research, I've seen & realized that I need to share a bucket first with IAM roles. I've read the documentation below but could not complete and understand it clearly.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage

My Requirements
1- Creating a sharing bucket for my organization and external user(s) which will allow operating (reading, writing, creating queries) data on Google Big Query.
2- Is there any option that users will read data but can not download the main database on Cloud Storage IAM roles?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the new "BigLake Tables" feature. This allows you to configure a BigLake table that uses a specific service account to access GCS. You can give access to the table to anyone but only give the service account access to the GCS bucket.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-cloud-storage-using-biglake